# UWP waiting for MediaPlayer to complete before continuing

Tags: uwp, media-player, wait, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I wish to give some audible instructions using media player. The computer tries to say:
"Enter your initials in the textbox and press enter"

One of four things happen

1) Event MediaPlayer.OnMediaPlayerFailed
2) Event MediaPlayer.OnMediaPlayerEnded
3) User completes the task and presses enter while MediaPlayer is still playing
4) User does nothing and we wish to time-out

MediaPlayer.Play() returns control to the next instruction before even starting to play the recording. The UI thread has to wait. But how? I decided that I would start a new task using Task.Run / Task.Factory.Run / Task.Factory.RunStart. And then Wait(timeout_interval) on the UI thread. But I just handed the same problem to the new thread / task. MediaPlayer.Play() is effectively the last line of the new task and completes before the sound finishes. I need to keep the task alive until OnMediaXxxx is executed. The two events would then the finish the task or cancel the UI.Wait()
I've been going round in circles with CancellationTokens, CancellationTokenSources and the myriad different ways of waiting.

What's the solution? What I'm trying to do doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I am sure there are multiple ways of doing it.. one of them is that you can have the textbox disabled initially and enable it when the media has played completely by waiting the thread for say 5 secs after the MediaPlayer starts playing the sound.

Answer (score 2):

I am now bald ... but successful. It all boiled down to waiting for the recording to finish. So I had a wait after the MediaPlay but this wasn't working. If I tried to play two consecutive sounds I couldn't get it to wait for the first to finish before it had a go at the second. But this did work...

```
static private void PlayAndWait(StorageFile file, double volume)
    {
        playCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        playTask = new Task(() => PlayFile(file, volume), playCancellationTokenSource.Token);
        playTask.Start();
        Task.WaitAny(new Task[] { playTask }, 15_0000);
    }

static private void PlayFile(StorageFile file, double volume)
    {
        if (MRecording.recordingStatus != RecordingStatus.Idle)
            throw new LogicException("PlayStorageFile: RecordingStatus not Idle");
        FileNowPlaying = file;
        var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer { AutoPlay = false, AudioCategory = MediaPlayerAudioCategory.Media };
        mediaPlayer.MediaFailed += OnMediaPlayerFailed; // one of these two should release the mutex
        mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += OnMediaPlayerEnded;
        mediaPlayer.AudioCategory = Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayerAudioCategory.Media;

        MediaSource mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
        var mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);
        mediaPlayer.Source = mediaPlaybackItem;
        mediaPlayer.Volume = volume;
        MRecording.recordingStatus = RecordingStatus.Playing;
        try
        {
            FileNowPlaying = file;
            mediaPlayer.Play();
            playTask.Wait(playCancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        { }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new LogicException("PlayFile", e);
        }
        FileNowPlaying = null;
        recordingStatus = RecordingStatus.Idle;
    }
    static void OnMediaPlayerFailed(object sender, MediaPlayerFailedEventArgs e) => PlayCleanUp();
static void OnMediaPlayerEnded(object sender, MediaPlayerFailedEventArgs e) => PlayCleanUp();
static void PlayCleanUp()
    {
        recordingStatus = RecordingStatus.Idle;
        if (playTask == null)
            throw new LogicException("playTask null");

        string msg = string.Empty;
        AggregateException exceptions = playTask.Exception;
        if (exceptions != null)
            foreach (Exception e in exceptions.InnerExceptions)
            {
                msg += e.Message + Statics.CRLF2;
                throw new LogicException("PlayCleanUp exception: " + msg);
            }
        playCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
```

So now I can do the following

```
PlayAndWait(StorageFile1, volume:1.0);
PlayAndWait(StorageFile2, volume:0.5);
PlayAndWait(StorageFile3, volume:0.7);
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a MediaPlayer extension method based on your answer that others may find useful.

```
public static class MediaPlayerExtensions
{
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public static async Task PlayAsync(this MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
    {
        mediaPlayer.MediaEnded -= MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
        mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;

        mediaPlayer.Play();

        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { _cancellationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle });
        });
    }

    private static void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();            
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private static async Task Play(InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream)
{
    var player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, "");

    await player.PlayAsync();            
}
```